# What would a bilabial or velar sibilant sound like?

Tags: fricatives, velar, bilabial

I know that a non-sibilant velar /x/ and non-sibilant bilabial fricative /ɸ/ is possible, and that alveolar fricatives have both sibilant /s/ and non-sibilant /θ/ forms, so what would a sibilant form of a velar and bilabial fricative sound like?